# Remove duplicate value from dictionary without removing key

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I'm new to Python and am having to learn by trial and error, but I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem I'm having.

I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
myDict = {'key1': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'key2': ['item4', 'item5', 'item6'],  
'key3': 'item7', 'key4': 'item8', 'key5': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'key6': 'item7'}
```

I need to remove duplicate values from the dictionary and replace them with an empty value (""). Found a couple solution on here but they are working as intended

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    if values not in key newDict.values():
        myDict[key] = value
    else:
        myDict[key] = ""
print newDict
```

This is removing all the values and is outputting

```
# newDict:{key1: '', key2: '', key3: '', key4: '', key5: '', key6: '')
```

I'm looking for the output to be

```
# newDict = {'key1': '', 'key2':['item4', 'item5', 'item6'], 'key3': '', 'key4':  
'item8', key5: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'key6': 'item7'}
```

Comment: Please post valid Python code: neither of those snippets are valid.

Comment: I changed the first snippet but I'm not sure how the lower portion of code should be changed

Comment: What is "newDict"?  Its not discussed anywhere.  Also, you're re-assignin the values of myDict, and never adding anything, or modifying newDict.  Please be more clear on what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to remove the content from inside the lists?  Are you only looking to remove values that are the same? (ie. in the situation ['item1'] and ['item1', 'item2'] do both stay unedited because they aren't exact matches?  Do both become ""?)

Comment: newDict={}, sorry forgot to include that. And with the code I posted I'm trying to fill a new dictionary with non-repeated values, but even better would be to simply modify the existing dictionary. I'm trying to remove items that are exactly alike (i.e. ['item1'] != ['item1','item2'] and therefore would not be replaced).

Comment: Updated the question to include the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right overall idea, but there are three problems with your code:

1. You're storing values back into `myDict` instead of into `newDict`.
2. On line 2, you're checking `values` instead of `value`.
3. Also on line 2, `key` shouldn't be there, and throws a `SyntaxError`.

Here is the correct code:

```
newDict = {}
for key, value in myDict.iteritems():
    if value not in newDict.values():
        newDict[key] = value
    else:
        newDict[key] = ""
print newDict
```

If you're not in the anti-ternary operator camp, you could also shorten it to this:

```
newDict = {}
for key, value in myDict.iteritems():
    newDict[key] = value if value not in newDict.values() else ""
print newDict
```

Or, if you would rather just remove the values from the original `dict` (`myDict`) instead of building a new one (`newDict`), you could do this:

```
foundValues = []
for key, value in myDict.iteritems():
    if value not in foundValues:
        foundValues.append(myDict[key])
    else:
        myDict[key] = ""
print myDict
```

If you need duplicate values removed in a specific order, check out [`OrderedDict`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

**Update:**

In light of the updated requirements -- that values be removed from the original `dict`, starting from the beginning -- if you're able to simply initialize `myDict` with an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict`, all you need to do is replace this:

```
myDict = {'key1': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'key2': ['item4', 'item5', 'item6'], 'key3': 'item7', 'key4': 'item8', 'key5': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'key6': 'item7'}
```

with this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

…

myDict = OrderedDict([('key1', ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']), ('key2', ['item4', 'item5', 'item6']), ('key3', 'item7'), ('key4', 'item8'), ('key5', ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']), ('key6', 'item7')])
```

and then use the same code provided above.

Comment: This worked as I had asked in the question, but I was hoping it would remove the first valued inputted. It did not so I'm going to have to do some work with OrderedDict to see if I can get the issue I'm having completely resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I added to the answer. Will that do?

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response, didn't get an email about a comment being made.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response, didn't get an email about a comment being made and I started working on another part of the project. When I combined the OrderDict code with the code above all I got was an empty OrderedDict and a list (foundValues) full of the values so I'm not sure what the foundValues is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
myDict_values = myDict.values() # better than calling this numerous times
for key in myDict.keys():
    if myDict_values.count(myDict[key]) > 1: myDict[key] = ""
```

This won't guarantee that `key5` will be blank instead of `key1`, because dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: The output on this code had both 'key5' and 'key1' empty. I need to leave the value in one of the keys.